# How to pass date from a widget before popping it in flutter?

Tags: android-studio, flutter, widget, hybrid

I am using a formfield widget from flutter
https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/datetime_picker_formfield

However, I want to pass the date that the user entered back to my previous widget (addReminder) but can't get to do that.

I have tried putting it in a static variable and accessing it but that did not work out, I am weak with dart so couldn't get the classes to have a mutual variable that I can use through initializing the widget as an object with a specific variable

And tried to get the variable through a getter but failed to do so.

**The parent widget that calls the class dateTime:**

```
 class addReminder extends StatelessWidget{
   dateTimeWidget = new dateTime();
 DateTime date;
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context){
 return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text('Add a Reminder'),

  ),
  body:
  new Container(
    padding: new EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
    child: new Form(
      child: new ListView(
        children: <Widget>[

          new TextFormField(
            keyboardType: TextInputType.text, // Use email input type for emails.
            decoration: new InputDecoration(
              hintText: 'Title of reminder',
            ),

          ),
          dateTimeWidget,
          RaisedButton(
            child: Text('Save'),
            onPressed:(){
              //This is where I want to extract the date and save it to a local variable (date in this case)
              Navigator.pop(context);

            },
          )
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

}
}

**The DateTime widget that uses 'DateTimePickerFormField' with both the widget and state class:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:datetime_picker_formfield/datetime_picker_formfield.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
class dateTime extends StatefulWidget{
  @override
 dateTimeState createState() => dateTimeState();

  }
   class dateTimeState extends State<dateTime>{

 static DateTime dateT;

 InputType inputType = InputType.both;

 final formats = {
 InputType.both: DateFormat("EEEE, MMMM d, yyyy 'at' h:mma"),
 InputType.date: DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd'),
InputType.time: DateFormat("HH:mm"),
 };

  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Container(
    child: DateTimePickerFormField(
     inputType: InputType.both,
     editable: true,
     format: formats[inputType],
     decoration: InputDecoration(
         labelText: 'Date/Time', hasFloatingPlaceholder: false),
     onChanged: (dt) => setState(() => dateT = dt),

   )


 );
```

}

I later on attempted this :

Added this method to the addReminder class:

```
  dateTimee(BuildContext context) async {
 final result = await Navigator.push(
    context,
  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=> dateTime()),
   );
```

}

and called it this way :

```
  dateTimee(context),
```

and in the dateTime class in the onchanged parameter I added

```
      onChanged: (dt) {
        setState(() => dateT = dt);
        Navigator.of(context).pop(dateT);
       },
```

However I get the error :

```
  I/flutter (18662): Another exception was thrown: 
  'package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart': Failed assertion: line1995 
  pos 12: '!_debugLocked': is not true.
```

I think it's because the method is of Future type where the call should be to a widget
So I don't know what to do
The widget I am calling which is dateTimee is based on calling the widget dateTimePickerFromField

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the cookbook https://flutter.io/docs/cookbook/navigation/returning-data

In summary: `Navigator.push` returns a future that will complete when the pushed widget calls `Navigator.pop`. You can pass a return value to `pop` to be the value that the future resolves with.

```dart
// In widget 1..
final result = await Navigator.of(context).push(...);

// In widget 2..
Navigator.of(context).pop('output');
```

Then once widget 2 calls pop, the future that widget 1 is awaiting will complete, and the `result` variable will be assigned to the `'output'` string.

Comment: couldn't do it :/